# JBoss EAP 6.1 server log rolls over at 12 noon and not at 00.00

Tags: logging, jboss

I've got a strange behaviour with the rolling of our log file on JBoss EAP 6.1.

We have configured the periodic-rotating-file-handler like this:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%X{username}][%X{cid}][%c{1}] (%3.5t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

The odd thing is that the logfile rotates at 12:00 and not at 00:00. Any idea why JBoss is doing that? On JBoss 5.1 it used to roll it over at 00:00. I can't see anything wrong in our configuration either.

Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Note, we are using LiveRebel, so if no one experienced these problems with JBoss directly then I might need to look at the LiveRebel configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in JBoss EAP 6.1, that has been fixed in EAP 6.1.1.

https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/544893